# Reshape a numpy array from (x,x,1) to (x,x)

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to reshape a numpy array from (32,32,1) to (32,32) so that I can plot an image of it using  `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()`.

I'm getting an invalid dimensions error for `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()`, so i assume it wants (32,32).

How can i reshape my numpy array to plot the image?

Comment: `arr = np.reshape(arr, (32,32))`

Comment: @hpaulj thank you, this worked.

Comment: Also `arr[:, :, 0]` or `arr[..., 0]`

Comment: arr.squeeze()  gets rid of the dims that are 1 https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1ba4173d20f16348f793c1d87f8cc03cd87588ad/numpy/core/src/multiarray/shape.c  line 526

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x.reshape([32,32])
np.squeeze(x)
x[:,:,0]
```

Any of those.